# Как в результат цикла завести переменную и в нее добавить еще переменных с текстом?

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, dataframe, итераторы

Как правильно написать вот такой код?

```
for named,dateful in adresat["FUL"].to_list(), adresat["dt"].to_list():
       mailbody = (Вас зовут: named, Ваша дата: dateful)
```

Причем какая странность, когда пишу:

```
for named in adresat["FUL"].to_list():
       print(named)
```

все ок, получаю все значения `named`. А как только пишу:

```
for named in adresat["FUL"].to_list():
       mailbody = named
print(mailbody)
```

получаю только последнее значения из списка.

Как правильно сделать, чтобы все значения были?

```
for named,dateful in adresat["FUL"].to_list(), adresat["dt"].to_list():
       mailbody = (Вас зовут: named, Ваша дата: dateful)

print (mailbody)
```

Что я хочу получить:

```
for named, dr in adresat["FUL"].to_list(),adresat["dt"].to_list():
       body=('Вас зовут: {}'.format(named), 'Ваш ДР: {}'.format(dr))
print(body)
```

по такому коду, что бы вывело:

```
Вас зовут: Иван Ваш ДР: 20.06
Вас зовут: Петя Ваш ДР: 23.06
```

А сейчас это выглядит так:

```
('Вас зовут: 2020-06-03 00:00:00', 'Ваш ДР: 2020-06-04 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU дополнил что хочу

Comment: ещё не хватает примера исходных данных...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]:
       ФИО            МЕЙЛ   ДАТА
0  Яковлев  yakovlev@ma.ru   2.06
1   Рубцов    rubcov@ma.ru  25.10
2  Кравцов   kravcov@ma.ru  23.10
```

Решение:

```
mail_body = "\n".join(["Вас зовут: {}\tВаш ДР: {}".format(x.ФИО, x.ДАТА)
                       for x in df.itertuples()])
print(mail_body)
```

Результат:

```
Вас зовут: Яковлев      Ваш ДР: 2.06
Вас зовут: Рубцов       Ваш ДР: 25.10
Вас зовут: Кравцов      Ваш ДР: 23.10
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Python 3.5.3

Comment: @user3119496, забыл, что вы используете устаревшую версию Python///

Comment: Да, почти получилось, но как только я mail_body беру и подставляю в сообщение, опять приходит только последнее значение. for addr in res["MAIL"].to_list():
    send_mail(addr, mailbody) получается затирается (

Comment: @user3119496, именно поэтому я всегда прошу уточнить вопрос! Вы написали "`хочу, что бы вывело ...`" - именно это вы и получили в моем ответе. Мы здесь пока не научились читать мысли, но мы работаем над этим) Повторюсь: __что именно вы хотите получить на выходе?__ Вы хотите получать строку - тело письма на каждой итерации цикла или список строк (писем) в результате работы цикла или что-то еще???

Comment: У меня 2 датафрейма, один с адресатами кому посылать, второй с теме кто ДР празднует, так вот мне надо сначала mailbody заполнить, теме кто празднует, и это mailbody отправить письмом, адресатам for x in adresat.itertuples():
    mailbody = "Наш коллега: {}\t: скоро празднует День Рождение, которое состоится: {}".format(x.FUL, x.dt)

print(mailbody)

for addr in res["MAIL"].to_list():
    send_mail(addr, mailbody)
типа того

Comment: @user3119496, это замечательно, но это совершенно не объясняет как именно вы хотите это сделать! Я вам уже три раза приводил в комментариях ссылку на то, как следует задавать вопросы по Pandas & Co. - советую все-таки прочитать разок. Сэкономите время и себе и тем, кто пытается вам помогать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108923/discussion-between-user3119496-and-maxu).